# How can we implement "Sleep Sort"?

Tags: parallelization, sorting

Inspired by [Implement Sleep Sort](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2722/826):

> Sleep Sort is an integer sorting algorithm I found on the Internet. It opens an output stream, and for each input numbers in parallel, delay for the number seconds and output that number. Because of the delays, the highest number will be outputted last.

I would like to know if it is possible to implement this in *Mathematica*.  As a version 7 user I would of course like to see a solution that works there, but I think that `RunScheduledTask` may be needed to accomplish this.

Comment: Sorry for not reading the link carefully!  Got it now :-)  That extra sentence makes a huge difference.  Gave an answer and +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an implementation that uses the scheduled tasks in version 8:

```
sleepSort[l_, t_:0.1] :=
  Scan[RunScheduledTask[Print[#];RemoveScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask], {t #}]&, l]
```

In a notebook environment, output will appear in the messages window.  The time interval is specified as the optional second argument, defaulting to 1/10th of a second (I'm impatient).  Don't set it too low, though -- the vagaries of the timing might produce results out of order.

Comment: brilliant ! I believe we do not need necessarily need `RemovScheduledTask[$ScheduledTask]` because this `sleepSort[L_List, t_: 1] :=  Scan[RunScheduledTask[Print[#], {t #}] &, L]` works equally well

Comment: @AliHashmi It is not _necessary_ to call `RemoveScheduledTask`, but if we don't then the list of `ScheduledTasks[]` will grow indefinitely.  It is good practice to clean up scheduled tasks when they are no longer needed, just as we should close opened files after using them.

Answer (score 11):

Note: While this whole post is just playing, the idea for the solution comes from [an answer to a very real problem I had](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/329/12), so it wasn't just a futile exercise.  The key is that (in v8) a shared function (set with `SetSharedFunction`) is always evaluated on the main kernel.  Thanks to [Andrew Moylan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/31/andrew-moylan) for pointing this out!

---

Here's my incredibly wasteful solution that makes you run out of kernel licenses:

```
In[16]:= CloseKernels[] (* just in case *)

In[17]:= list = RandomInteger[10, 10]    
Out[17]= {3, 2, 10, 8, 1, 0, 5, 10, 8, 10}

In[18]:= LaunchKernels@Length[list]

In[19]:= ParallelSow = Sow
         SetSharedFunction[ParallelSow]

Out[19]= Sow

In[21]:= Reap@ParallelDo[Pause[i]; ParallelSow[i], {i, list}]    
Out[21]= {Null, {{0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10}}}

In[22]:= CloseKernels[]
```

---

**EDIT**

Another solution, should be v7 compatible.  Just evaluate all of it at once.

```
CloseKernels[];

list = RandomSample@Range[10]

LaunchKernels@Length[list];

jobs = {ParallelSubmit /@ ((Pause[#]; #) &) /@ Hold @@ list} // 
  ReleaseHold

Reap@NestWhile[Function[j, (Sow[#1]; #3) & @@ WaitNext[j]], 
  jobs, # =!= {} &]

CloseKernels[];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I wanted to show it works even if the list has duplicates.  I don't know how precise `Pause` is though ...

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot 7 doesn't have `SetSharedFunction`!

Comment: Stay tuned, v7 version is compatible coming

Comment: Incidentally it appears to work if I use `Sow` rather than `ParallelSow`, or simply `Print`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See my edit

Comment: Both of your methods work.  Can you see a way to nicely gather results as you do, while using the `Dynamic` method I posted?

Answer (score 11):

Here is my attempt to do this with a single kernel.  Output is printed directly to the messages channel, and you cannot suppress the output of `f /@ list` because if the `Dynamic` expressions never display they never run.

```
list = RandomInteger[10, 10]
f = Module[{x},
      (x := If[start + # < AbsoluteTime[], Print[#]; x =.]);
      Dynamic[Refresh[x, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
    ] &;

start = AbsoluteTime[]; f /@ list
```

Comment: This is not an attempt, it's a solution.  I like better like this: change `Print[#]` to `AppendTo[result,#]`, set `result = {}` at the beginning, and put a `Dynamic[result]` somewhere to watch it in real time.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version that cheats and works by using bash 
(or probably almost any other *nix shell). 
It places the sorted list into the file `tmp` in the current directory.

```
sleepSort[lst_?(VectorQ[#, Positive] &)] :=  Do[
  Run["(sleep " <> n <> "; echo " <> n <> " >> tmp)&"], {n, ToString/@lst}]
```

See the output at [Mathematica/Bash sleep sort](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9NdSnli__E)