# The conditions used in Sum or ParallelSum: Calling a function/variable

Tags: parallelization, summation, conditional, variable

For some reason, I encounter a problem when doing the Sum and ParallelSum (or doing the Do or ParallelDo, e.g. [such as the issue here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/parallel-and-non-parallel-functions-return-different-results)), I figured that the potential cause of the problem can be resolved if I find a way to evaluate the following test toy model without calling the variable i twice at i == 3 || i== 5 as,

```
Sum[If[i == 3 ||i== 5, i, 0], {i, 0, 10}]
```

or

```
ParallelSum[If[i == 3 ||i== 5, i, 0], {i, 0, 10}]
```

but just combine the calling of i once as

```
Sum[If[i == (3 || 5), i, 0], {i, 0, 10}].
```

Obviously, the i == (3 || 5) does not work, which is unreadable in Mathematica.

**My question:** Is there any way to express i == 3 || i== 5 such that i is only called once? So it saves the time by the i once, instead of calling i twice and evaluate its value separately comparing to 3 and then comparing to 5.

p.s. The reason I asked this is because in general the i in my program is a very complicated function of multivariable, and evaluate such a function causes enormous times. For example, it could be something like

```
Sum[If[f[i,j,k] == 3 || f[i,j,k] == 5, i, 0], {i, 0, 2^10}, {j, 0, 2^10}, {k, 0, 2^10}]
```

where f[i,j,k] is a earlier defined complicated complex integrations/contour integrals, etc. If there is a way to express

```
 Sum[If[f[i,j,k] == (3 || 5), i, 0], {i, 0, 2^10}, {j, 0, 2^10}, {k, 0, 2^10}]
```

it will be easier. **Thanks in advance for the answers from experts!**

---

(Note) One resolution, of course, is to define a variable g as the g=function f[i,j,k], so that

```
 Sum[If[(g == 3 || g == 5)/.g-> f[i,j,k], i, 0], {i, 0, 2^10}, {j, 0, 2^10}, {k, 0, 2^10}]
```

this indeed works. However, it does not work and potentially gives wrong answer when we consider the ParallelSum,

```
 ParallelSum[If[(g == 3 || g == 5)/.g-> f[i,j,k], i, 0], {i, 0, 2^10}, {j, 0, 2^10}, {k, 0, 2^10}]
```

Or write the ParallelDo version of the above to do the sum. The trouble seems that the g variable is parallelly used simultaneously, so it causes the confusion.

Comment: I think `MatchQ[i, 3 | 5]` will work for you.

Comment: Great, thanks! Carl