# How to determine how much of a table is generated?

Tags: evaluation, monitoring

If I'm generating a table from a slow function, like this:

```
foo = Table[SuperSlowExpression, {1000}]
```

is there a way to determine *after submission* (so it is too late to instrument the call) to find out how many values already have been generated (so that when it takes longer than expected I can find out whether to wait a bit longer or to abort the calculation)?

So is there still a way to get at the information? Note that there is no iteration variable in the call which I could read.

Optimally, I'd also want to get the already calculated values, of course.

**Edit:**

Since this seems to have been consistently overlooked:

**This is about a calculation which is already running. It is no longer possible to make changes to the call of `Table` or to the expression inside.**

Comment: I don't know about after, but if you already know that you have `SuperSlowExpression` to begin with, it seems worthwhile to set up a cache variable beforehand, and then modify `SuperSlowExpression` to store to the cache (with e.g. `Append[]`/`AppendTo[]`) with each iteration within `Table[]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given your current situation, there is another option that *might* help if you have set `"Enable notebook history tracking"` in `Preferences > Advanced`:

[image]

Then, you go to `Cell > Notebook history` and navigate to your currently evaluating cell and look at the time stamp when you last edited it. Chances are that you edited it just prior to evaluating (note that if you open an old notebook and execute the cell right away, this might not work, because the last edit timestamp will not be what you want it to be).

[image]

Now find the current time from your system clock. Assuming you know how long it takes for one evaluation of `SuperSlowExpression`, you can now simply do:

$$\mathrm{approx\ progress=\frac{current\ time - last\ edited\ time}{time\ for\ one\ evaluation}}$$

This will give you a rough estimate of the progress — enough to make a decision whether to wait a bit longer or to give up.

Remember, this should be a ***last ditch option***! There are many ifs and buts here, but seeing as all the other options require an iterator and you don't have one (and your `Table` is running), it's worth trying...

Comment: Thank you. This seems indeed to be the best option available. And the history tracking was up to now unknown to me (it turned out that it already was enabled, though). While your advice came too late for me (I stopped the calculation before I saw it; however a later, monitored run showed me that it was indeed the correct thing to do), it's really what I should have done (with estimating the time of one step by simply entering a subsession and timing a single evaluation of the expression).

Answer (score 20):

Yes, there is.  You can use `Monitor`

```
Monitor[
  Table[Pause[1]; i, {i, 10}],
  i
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Some explanations**

`Table` uses dynamic scoping to localize its variable (`i` in this case), just like `Block`. This means that while `Table` is evaluating, `i` has a "global" value that one can inspect even from outside the `Table` if we interrupt the evaluation.

On way of interrupting the evaluation is to request `i`'s value on the pre-emptive link (i.e. using `Dynamic` expressions) We could just put `Dynamic[i]` somewhere and it would count up just like `Manipulate` while the `Table` is evaluating.

Another way of interrupting the evaluation is through entering a `Dialog`:  You can use the `Evaluation -> Interrupt evaluation...` menu item, choose `Enter subsession`. You will get a prompt where you can inspect the kernel state (including the value of `i`, `Stack[]`, etc.).  Evaluate `Return[]` to resume he evaluation.

I have been using both of these techniques extensively to monitor very lengthy evaluations.  The second one even seems to work for parallel evaluations, and least in those cases where I tried it.

**Iteration variable and already calculated values**

If there is no iteration variable in the `Table`, just insert one, and use `Table[..., {i, 1000}]`.  Then we can use `Monitor` or `Dynamic[i]`.

It is not possible to get the already calculated values.  If you want to do this (it would often be desirable to be able to!), you need to implement your own version of `Table`.  I asked about how to implement an interruptible parallel `Table` or `Map` [in this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-collect-result-continuously-interruptible-calculation-when-running-para).  The solution I got does not allow inspecting the so far calculated results, but it lets me interrupt the calculation, and continue from where I stopped later.

**A `table` function that allows monitoring partial results**

As an example, I provide a custom `table` function that allows monitoring the partial results.

Try evaluating

```
Dynamic[table`Results[]]
table[Pause[1]; i^2, {i, 10}]
```

``table`Results[]` could be used in `Monitor` too.

I am using a linked list to collect the results for better performance than what `AppendTo` would give. I cannot use `Sow`/`Reap` here because they don't allow inspecting the partial results (at least I am not aware of this being possible).

*Note:* If you use nested `table`s, only the inner one can be monitored, but all of them will work correctly.

---

The code:

```
ClearAll[table, table`result, table`Results]
SetAttributes[table, HoldAll]

table`result = {};

table[expr_, iterator__] :=
 Block[{table`result, table`elem},
  table`result = {};
  Do[
   table`result = {table`result, table`elem[expr]},
   iterator
   ];
  table`Results[]
  ]

table`Results[] := Block[{table`res, table`elem},
  table`res = Flatten[table`result];
  table`elem = Identity;
  table`res
  ]
```

Comment: "Note that there is no iteration variable in the call which I could read." - so, how does one use `Monitor[]` here?

Comment: As I said, it's a calculation which *already started* (had I had an idea that it could take that long, I would have instrumented it accordingly). That is, I cannot wrap it any more into a monitor or modify the expression. However a +1 for the idea to use a linked list instead of a built-in list for speed.

Comment: @celtschk So you are running the calculation *right now*?  You're out of luck then.  I've been there.

Comment: @celtschk For a few more custom Table functions (conditional Table and Abortable table), see my posts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367932/generate-a-list-in-mathematica-with-a-conditional-tested-for-each-element/6368770#6368770, and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470625/mathematica-table-function/6471024#6471024. They are based on `Reap` and `Sow` and don't allow the "real-time" monitoring, but can be modified using @Szabolcs's suggestion, to allow that. They however accept a general syntax of `Table`, including the multi-dimensional case.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, I'm running it just now. I *grossly* underestimated the running time, and I have no idea of *how* grossly I underestimated it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thank you for the links. The abortable table is exactly what I wish I had used.

Comment: @celtschk Glad I could help. I may add the real-time monitoring capabilities to those functions in the future, as time permits. You may also find this very useful answer by WReach interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287817/the-best-way-to-construct-a-function-with-memory/5291299#5291299.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Thanks, but memoizing doesn't help in my case because the results contain randomness; indeed, memoizing in my case would result in the exact same value repeated 1000 times ― much faster to calculate, but not very useful :-)

Comment: @celtschk Did you notice the link I included in my original answer to another abortable table implementation, which is also *parallelized*?

Comment: @celtschk In this context, the reason I gave you that link is not the memoization part but the part of *backing things up* (persistency), via SQL or disk, so that you don't lose the data in case of Aborts, crashes, etc.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Actually I missed it, thanks for pointing to it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Ah, I didn't notice that part. But then, since I couldn't get at the data, my chances to write it to disk were zero anyway.

Comment: @celtschk I see. It wasn't originally clear whether you were seeking a general advice on how to do this or an advice on how to save the data you already computed in a computation you were running right then (and in the latter case, which apparently was your situation,  there is little one can do, I think, unless this possibility had been anticipated from the start. I've been there many times, but it was some 5-6 years ago).

Answer (score 8):

Similar, with a progress bar:

```
tEnd = 10;
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[i], {0, tEnd}]
Table[Pause[1]; i, {i, tEnd}]
```

Comment: As I said, *the calculation is already started* and *does not have an iteration variable*. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @celtschk, you can execute a FrontEndTokenExecute with "SubsessionEvaluateCells" and incrementing and i=0 via $Post. ;-) But you know what: stop the execution and add a i in your table.

Comment: If with "stop" you mean "interrupt", then telling how to add an `i` after the fact would be exactly an answer to my question. If by "stop" you mean "abort" then that's exactly what I'd like to avoid. I'd hate to lose more than half a day of calculation while thinking that *maybe* it might have finished the next minute if I didn't kill it. Of course if the answer to my question should be "it's not possible" then of course that is what I'll have to do (actually with a new run I'll then make sure to get the actual *data* early).

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you're evaluating something *slightly* different:

```
Table[Pause[0.1](*SuperSlowExpression*), {i, 1000}]
```

You can create a cell containing `i`, and use **Evaluation > Evaluate in Subsession** to see the current value of `i` without interrupting the main evaluation.  In the case where you don't have an iterator variable to inspect, then the question is whether there is some state or property in your `SuperSlowExpression` that could be evaluated to get an idea of how much progress has been made.

Comment: I suggested this as well.  But a question, since I don't really know anyone else who uses this actively:  is this safe when doing parallel evaluations, especially in the case when TCPIP links are used between kernels?  (Is there a chance that something will time out in a MathLink connection, messing up things irreparably?)

Answer (score 6):

If you're using a function that doesn't use iterators such as `Scan` or `Fold` you could consider using `PrintTemporary`, for example

```
f[x_] := (Pause[2]; Sin[x]);
res = {};
Module[{i = 0, temp},
  Scan[(NotebookDelete[temp];
    temp = PrintTemporary[++i];
    AppendTo[res, f[#]]) &, Range[20]]]
```

Comment: If we're already setting a variable to a value, then we can `Monitor` again...

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried that but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ignore that last comment, I just realized I made a mistake when I tried to Monitor before