# Dynamic[] and Print[]

Tags: dynamic

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Intermediate display similar to PrintTemporary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/intermediate-display-similar-to-printtemporary)
>   [Estimating progress on plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5985/5)
>   [How to create a progress bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5978/5)
>   [How to determine how much of a table is generated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1489/5)

I'm trying to print an output from every iteration of a `Do[]` loop, but without it continuing down the notebook.  I want the `Print[]` output to be overwritten in the same cell with the new value.  Here is a MWE of what I'm trying, but I can't seem to get the expected behavior.

```
Do[
  If[i==1,
    Print["Output = ", Dynamic[i]]
  ]
,{i,10}
]
```

So in other words, on the first iteration, I want to see "Output = 1", and then every subsequent iteration I want to see the 1 change to a 2, 3, 4, etc. in the same cell.

Comment: One idea is to use `PrintTemporary`.

Comment: @PlatoManiac Post an answer!

Comment: @Verde I am so so incorrigibly lazy! Thx for motivating...

Comment: Some more related near duplicates (if others want to choose alternatives): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5985/5, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5978/5, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1489/5

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Monitor` like :

```
Monitor[Do[Pause[3], {i, 1, 10^3}], i]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way,

```
Print["Output = ", Dynamic[j]];
Do[j = i; Pause[0.1];, {i, 10}]
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many, many possibilities to achieve something like that. If you want to use `Dynamic`, you could set a global value which you observe

```
Dynamic[globalWatch]

Do[
 If[OddQ[i], globalWatch = i];
 Pause[.1];
 ComplicatedCalculation[i],
 {i, 100}
 ]
```

I always suspect, whether `Do` is really needed, but sometimes when I for instance iterate over a list of files I want to process, I use it too. In such a situation, I use `PrintTemporary` as suggested by PlatoManiac to see the progress. `PrintTemporary` is nice because you can print all information you like and no matter it fills the screen, it gets erased after the computation is done.