# ParallelMap and Sow/Reap - not behaving as expected?

Tags: programming, parallelization

**Is ParallelMap and Parallelize@Map expected to work with Sow and Reap construct.**

*This is a rather brief toy code to find all Primes just to force the use of Sow/Reap inside Map*

```
Reap[Map[
   If[PrimeQ@#, Sow@#] &,
   Range[10]
   ]][[2]]
```

and the output is, as expected

```
{{2, 3, 5, 7}}
```

But when I do

```
Reap[Parallelize@Map[
    If[PrimeQ@#, Sow@#] &,
    Range[1000]
    ]][[2]]
```

I got the output

```
{}
```

And the same was the output when I ran

```
Reap[
  ParallelMap[
   If[PrimeQ@#, Sow@#] &,
   Range[10]
   ]
  ][[2]]
```

**2 questions :**

1) How is this explainable ?

2) If this is the case, how do I efficiently I spawn parallel jobs which accumulate something ?

Answer (score 8):

I guess this will work! Check documentation for `SetSharedFunction` but be careful of the parallel overhead of following implementation.

```
SetSharedFunction[PSow];
PSow[x_] := Sow[x];
Reap[Parallelize@Map[If[PrimeQ@#, PSow@#] &, Range[10]]][[2]]
```

> {{2, 5, 3, 7}}

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend parallelizing these types of calculations using the [`ParallelCombine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelCombine.html) paradigm.

First, let's make a function out of your example:

```
fun = Function[list, Reap[Map[If[PrimeQ@#, Sow@#] &, list]][[2, 1]]]
```

The non-parallel version will be `fun[Range[200]]`.  Parallelize it using

```
ParallelCombine[
 fun,
 Range[200],
 Join
]
```

I spelt out `Join` here because in other applications you may need a different function there.  Here it can be omitted.

---

This is clearly more work than the ([also valid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/329/12)) `SetSharedFunction` approach, but it is going to avoid some overhead.  `SetSharedFunction` simply forces the function to be evaluated on the main kernel.  If the equivalent of `PrimeQ` for your real calculation gives `True` for a sizeable fraction of the values, the `SetSharedFunction`-based parallelization won't buy much performance, or might even be slower than a serial computation.

Comment: Thanks for sueggesting ParallelCombine. An interesting find!

Comment: But how is this behavior of Reap@Map@Sow giving {} explainable?

Comment: @myaccount_ram You were running `Sow` in a subkernel and `Reap` in the main kernel, so it can't work.  These are separate processes that do not share any memory.  The main kernel merely submits evaluations to the subkernels and collects results.