# Reap, Sow with Parallelize: bad performance, why?

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, parallelization, sow-reap

I have a question about the performance of Reap and Sow with Parallelize. I am aware of the following questions

- [How to collect result continuously (interruptible calculation) when running parallel calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-collect-result-continuously-interruptible-calculation-when-running-para)
- [ParallelMap and Sow/Reap - not behaving as expected? [duplicate]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/parallelmap-and-sow-reap-not-behaving-as-expected)

and the Wolfram tips

- [Jon McLoone: 10 Tips for Writing Fast Mathematica Code](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/)
- [Andrew Moylan: Mathematica Q&A: Sow, Reap, and Parallel Programming](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/04/20/mathematica-qa-sow-reap-and-parallel-programming/)

but the following code shows (at least for this simple evaluation on my computer), that parallelization using Reap and Sow is somehow slow for this case

```
n = 10^3*2;
(*AppendTo*)
data1 = {};
Do[AppendTo[data1, x], {x, 0, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Reap and Sow, no parallelization*)
data2 = Reap[Do[Sow[x], {x, 0, n}]][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
data2 == data1
(*Reap and Sow, with parallelization*)
SetSharedFunction[ParallelSow];
ParallelSow[expr_] := Sow[expr];
data3 = Reap[Parallelize[Do[ParallelSow[x], {x, 0, n}]]][[2,1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Sort[data3] == data1
```

Here is the output

```
{0.015600, Null}
{0., Null}
True
{7.784414, Null}
True
```

Of course, all data are identical. For n=10^3*2 AppendTo is ok (not as fast as Reap and Sow, just increase n) but the parallelized version is horrible.

Question1: Why?

Question2: How would you parallelize this instead? I need to evaluate a huge program several times and I am interested only in saving the results (with Reap and Sow). Each run of the program is independent of all others (simple evaluations) so it can be parallelized. But now ParallelSow seems to be the bottle neck and I cannot think of another way.

Comment: Do you mean the same as the answer of Mr.Wizard?

Comment: Not exactly, but more or less. Sorry, I had your question open in my browser for a couple of days since I meant to make a comment, but I didn't reload it to see that there was an answer. I suppose I'll delete my comment now since it seems to add nothing important to what you already know.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In *Mathematica* every inter-Kernel communication comes with significant overhead.  Your simple `Do` loop with a shared `Sow` on every value is about the worst possible situation.  Instead (for performance) you want to gather results *within* each Kernel and only pass them back to the master in a single call.  (Or at least a limited number of calls.)

Using linked lists e.g. `{{{n1}, n2}, n3}` followed by [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) will prevent the slow-down of `AppendTo` on long lists.

```
n = 1*^5;

(*AppendTo*)
data1 = {};
Do[AppendTo[data1, x], {x, 0, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming

(*Reap and Sow, no parallelization*)
data2 = Reap[Do[Sow[x], {x, 0, n}]][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
data2 == data1

(*linked list*)
ParallelEvaluate[foo = {}];
sow[x_] := (foo = {foo, x};)
ParallelDo[sow[x], {x, 0, n}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(data3 = Join @@ ParallelEvaluate[Flatten@foo];) // AbsoluteTiming
data1 === Sort[data3]
```

> {17.288, Null}
>
> {0.0431217, Null}
>
> True
>
> {0.0527825, Null}
>
> {0.0282877, Null}
>
> True

The example chosen is probably overly simplistic and other measures may be needed for real-world problems.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!