# Bags don't work in parallel code?

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization, internals

Appending to a list in parallel works:

```
b = {};
SetSharedVariable[b]
WaitAll[Table[ParallelSubmit[{p}, AppendTo[b, 1]], {p, 3}]];
(* b is now {1,1,1} *)
```

But stuffing a `Bag` in parallel doesn't:

```
b = Internal`Bag[];
SetSharedVariable[b]
ParallelDo[Internal`StuffBag[b, 1], {3}]
Internal`BagPart[b, All]
(* b is now {} *)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84534/reap-sow-with-parallelize-bad-performance-why and its linked Q&As.