# How to use Reap and Sow with ParallelDo

Tags: parallelization, sow-reap

Consider the two cases:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
j = Reap[Do[{Sow[{i, i}, a]}; Sow[{i, i^2}, b], {i, 100}], _, Rule];
a /. Last@j
h = Reap[ParallelDo[{Sow[{i, i}, a]}; Sow[{i, i^2}, b], {i, 100}], _, 
   Rule];
a /. Last@h
```

The output of the first is a matrix, while the output of the second is `a`. I am obviously using `ParallelDo`, `Sow` and `Reap` in the wrong way.

Which is the correct way to use `Reap` and `Sow` with a `ParallelDo`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using the parallelization functions with `Sow` and `Reap`? From what I read in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84534 they're not likely to perform well with each other to begin with. Normally divergent results between `Do` and `ParallelDo` is going to be an inter-kernel communication issue or a failure to share definitions, but I'm not sure you should expect any performance benefit even if you fix that issue.

Comment: I have the same concerns as eyorble, but I am also not sure. It might be a better choice to collect results per kernel first (maybe even in an `Association` (per kernel, of course)) and to `Merge` the results afterwards.

Comment: In order to obtain the desired output, you have to execute `SetSharedFunction[Sow]` in advance.