# Efficient memory usage while building a large sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, memory, sparse-arrays

I am sure the following problem has been solved already, but I am unable to find any solution... Any help appreciated!

So I am building a pretty huge matrix (or tensor, actually) using

`mat=SparseArray[ParallelTable[UnitStep[f[a,b,c,d]],{a,1,D},{b,1,D},{c,1,D},{d,1,D}]]]`

In my specific case I have `D=180` and `f` is a simple function (basically addition or subtraction of certain elements stored in a short list), such that the majority of the values `UnitStep[f[...]]` are zeros and the resulting matrix is indeed sparse.

Now, constructing this array takes quite some time, but more problematically, it uses around 12 GB of memory during the computation. I want to use less memory, but I do not know how. However, I think it should be possible because it is a very sparse array containing only zeros and a few ones. In particular, using

`Export["mat.mx",max]`

the final file on my computer is only 12 **M**B (instead of **G**B). Is there a better way?

Comment: Without the specific definition of `f`, it's hard to give advice. Anyway, if I have to guess, building the `SparseArray` from rules rather than converting a normal tensor to a `SparseArray` should help. (See the examples in document of `SparseArray` for more info. )

Comment: Memoizing `f` may be more efficient than parallelizing. But as @xzczd says, nothing can be said without details on `f`.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question. Even though the author never stated that explicitly, looking at the form of the SparseArray construction, which uses `UnitStep`, and given the information that the resulting sparse matrix is much smaller than the intermediate result, it is possible to conclude that `UnitStep[f[...]]` produces mostly zeros, and that the author wants to avoid consuming too much memory for the intermediate result. After that assumption, the question becomes well-defined.

Comment: `mat = SparseArray[Reap[Do[val = UnitStep[f[a, b, c, d]];
      If[val != 0, Sow[{a, b, c, d} -> val]], {a, 1, top}, {b, 1, 
       top}, {c, 1, top}, {d, 1, top}]][[2, 1]]];`

Comment: ...and I now see this is old and already had an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though you have shared no details about `f`, as others have mentioned, I think I understand your problem.

Consider this (note that `D` is a protected symbol in Mathematica):

```
dim = 40;
x = ParallelTable[
  UnitStep[a - b - c - d], 
  {a, 1, dim}, {b, 1, dim}, {c, 1, dim}, {d, 1, dim}];
y = SparseArray[x];
```

On my machine, `x` occupies 65 MB of memory while `y` just 3 MB. So when you do

```
z = SparseArray[ParallelTable[
    UnitStep[a - b - c - d], 
    {a, 1, dim}, {b, 1, dim}, {c, 1, dim}, {d, 1, dim}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.600104, Null} *)
```

Mathematica uses 65 MB of memory to store the intermediate calculation result.

Instead, you can generate the list of rules for `SparceArray` directly:

```
zz = SparseArray[Reap[Do[
       If[UnitStep[a - b - c - d] == 1, Sow[{a, b, c, d} -> 1]],
       {a, 1, dim}, {b, 1, dim}, {c, 1, dim}, {d, 1, dim}
     ]][[2, 1]], {dim, dim, dim, dim}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {3.55455, Null} *)

z == zz (* True *)
```

The code above is not parallelized and is 5.6x slower than the original on my machine, which has 8 cores. You cannot naively parallelize `Sow`, but you can use  [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard)'s [trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84534/reap-sow-with-parallelize-bad-performance-why?noredirect=1&lq=1) with minimal performance loss over the original solution (and significant memory gain!).

```
ParallelEvaluate[foo = {}];
sow[x_] := (foo = {foo, x};)
ParallelDo[
   If[UnitStep[a - b - c - d] == 1, sow[{a, b, c, d} -> 1]],
   {a, 1, dim}, {b, 1, dim}, {c, 1, dim}, {d, 1, dim}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(zzz = SparseArray[
     Flatten@ParallelEvaluate[Flatten@foo], 
     {dim, dim, dim, dim}];) // AbsoluteTiming

{0.444935, Null}
{0.299598, Null}

zzz == z (* True *)
```

Comment: Dear Victor K. Thanks for the answer, that solved exactly the problem (although unfortunately I am not able to understand Mr.Wizard's code to the detail, but it works!). And indeed, ```f``` was pretty much the function you wrote down, with the only difference that it called elements ```list[[a]]``` from a list instead of directly adding/substracting ```a,b,c,d```. However, I think this neither slows down the code nor does it suck up memory (unless , maybe,```list''' is huge, but it isn't). Thx!

Comment: Glad it helped!