# Why it is not possible to Append list in ParallelDo?

Tags: parallelization

I'm trying to run long calculations, so I need to run it in parallel. I'm running two nested `Do`, and it works fine until I put `ParallelDo` instead of one of `Do`.

```
aaa = {};
Do[Do[aaa = Append[aaa, {i, j}], {j, 1, 5}], {i, 4}]
aaa
```

What is happening and how I can run two nested `Do` one of which is parallel?

Comment: `Append` is a terribly inefficient way of constructing a list. Please look into [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) or [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html).

Comment: If you use `AppendTo` it works. Try `aaa = {}; Do[Do[AppendTo[aaa, {i, j}], {j, 1, 5}], {i, 4}]` and check `aaa`. One gets the list you want by `Table` easier and faster. But perhaps, your problem is more complex than described in the question.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch your code uses `Do`, not `ParallelDo`.

Comment: @Victor K. Exactly as that of OP. I guess that OP calls that "parallel do." Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: OP states that his code (which works with `Do`) stops working with `ParallelDo`. Your `AppendTo` code is also unlikely to work with parallelization - you cannot assign to the same variable across multiple threads, without some additional tricks.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer.**

Here is [my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279094/efficient-memory-usage-while-building-a-large-sparse-matrix/279098#279098) to a different question that illustrates how you can build a list in parallel.

**Long answer.**

First of all, you should not use `Append` to incrementally build lists, as pointed out by [@Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26598/roman). Lists are implemented as arrays inside Mathematica, and so `Append`, effectively, copies the **whole** array at every iteration. The following takes 3 seconds on my machine:

```
aaa = {}; Do[aaa = Append[aaa, i], {i, 50000}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

There are two useful idioms to avoid this copying: (a) create a linked list, or (b) use `Sow` and `Reap`.

```
bbb = {}; Do[bbb = {bbb, i}, {i, 50000}]; bbb = Flatten[bbb]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.024124, Null} *)

ccc = Reap[Do[Sow[i], {i, 50000}]][[2, 1]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.019154, Null} *)

aaa == bbb == ccc
(* True *)
```

However, you cannot directly use `Sow` and `Reap` with Parallel do as [described here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84534/reap-sow-with-parallelize-bad-performance-why). And the double-linked trick wouldn't work either, because the parallel kernel that executes your code needs to modify the same variable. The `ParallelEvaluate` in the above-linked solution solves this problem.

Comment: Using Append is not the problem since it will happen about 10 times only. The question was why it does not work in ParallelDo. And I could not fined the answer to this question in your Short or Long answer.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a statement `x = x + 1` is executed in 8 threads in parallel? What will the value of `x` be the end of it, if it started at 0?

Comment: See also “Possible Issues” section in `ParallelDo` documentation.