# Finish calculation on user Input

Tags: input

Lets say I have a calculation in a form of

```
Table[myStuff[i],{i,0,k}]
```

Is there a way to avoid a fixed `k` but instead end the loop after an abitrary amount of time with an user input.

Such that I can start the calculation in the evening and just stop it in the morning without having to estimate a `k`.

Comment: `Table[myStuff[i], {i, 0, Dialog[]}]`?

Comment: I'd propose: `i = 0;
While[i < Infinity, myStuff[i]; i++]`; after aborting you can get `i`. You'd have to figure out how do you want to store the values of `myStuff[i]` (I don't know in detail what are you doing so this is just a hint), but it might turn out to be inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `myStuff` is the following function:

```
myStuff[i_] := (Pause[1]; i^2)
```

Then run this:

```
result = 
 Module[{i = 1, s = {}},
  CheckAbort[
   While[True, s = {s, myStuff[i]}; i++], Flatten@s]]

(*{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49}*)
```

This is the required table when aborted after 7 seconds.

See [this](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node525.html) for details on why using `s = {s, myStuff[i]}` is very efficient.

The below plot shows how this method, the Sow/Reap method in the other answer, and the method using Join scales with the size of the table:

[image: BenchmarkPlot]

Comment: No need to `Flatten`: `s = s~Join~{myStuff[i]}`.

Comment: I bet that's slower for large lists, since you are copying the entire list. Whereas I am creating a linked list, which has much more efficient insertions

Comment: see http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node525.html

Comment: Similar with `Reap` and `Sow` that avoids the pitfall @dan7geo points out:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-collect-result-continuously-interruptible-calculation-when-running-para/329#329

Answer (score 1):

To expound on my comment, drawing inspiration from [How to collect result continuously (interruptible calculation) when running parallel calculations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/313/how-to-collect-result-continuously-interruptible-calculation-when-running-para/329#329) you could do, for example,

```
myStuff[i_] := (Pause[1]; i^2)
Module[{i = 1},
    Last[Last[Reap[
        CheckAbort[
            While[True, Sow[myStuff[i]]; i++], 
            ignored
            ]
    ]]]
]
```

Interrupting after ~5 seconds gives `{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}`.

Comment: I added CheckAbort 33 seconds before your answer :)

Comment: Ha.  I'd still be concerned about the speed of `s={s, myStuff[i]}`---doesn't it evaluate s when the list on the RHS gets constructed?

Comment: Not really. It's a call by reference thing which doesn't copy the list. Just uses a pointer to the list or something. I forgot the actual details of it.

Comment: Hm.  You seem to be right. `Map[
 Module[{s}, 
   s = {}; {#, Timing[For[i = 0, i < #, i++, s = {s, i}]][[1]]}] &, 2^
 Range[1, 20]]; ListPlot[%]`

Comment: see benchmark plot in my answer