# How to parallelize Reap and Sow in Mathematica 14.0.0?

Tags: parallelization, sow-reap, version-14

I'm working with a huge amount of data, so I'm avoiding using `AppendTo`. I used to use the `Reap` and `Sow` command, in parallel, as follows:

```
SetSharedFunction[ParallelSow];
ParallelSow[expr_] := Sow[expr]

list = Reap[ParallelDo[psa= Eigenvalues[Adj$A, -1];
psaData = {N[Abs@psa, Prec][[1]]};
ParallelSow[psaData], {s, lists}]][[2,1]]
```

Everything worked fine until I updated *Mathematica* to version 14.0.0. Now, all my attempts give me

```
{Null, {}}
```

If, however, I use just `Do` and `Sow` (or `ParallelSow` as defined above), the code works fine!

What changed? Can anyone help me regain the old functionality?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, the document page _Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1_ doesn't mention anything about this. (BTW, a simpler example is the one in **Neat Examples** section of document of `SetSharedFunction`. It simply doesn't work now. ) Have you reported this to WRI?

Comment: Frankly, I'm kinda shocked that `Sow` even works though parallel functions. I don't think it's documented anywhere that it should work? As a workaround, you can always use an `Association` to `AppendTo`. It's much faster than appending to a list.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit As mentioned above, it's documented in **Neat Examples** section of document of  `SetSharedFunction`. See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/313/1871

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Sorry. In that case it's definitely a bug. I'll report it.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. I reported it to support and they responded saying that "It appears that Reap/Sow is not behaving correctly with Parallel kernels in Mathematica 14".

Thanks, @Sjoerd Smit, I'll try to use  `Association`.

Comment: I also heard that it should be fixed in the next version, so that's good news.